# Trying to use php functions on school server, getting "could not find driver" error

Tags: php, unix

I'm trying to use php for a class project, and I'm getting this error when I try to create a database connection.  My connection code is as follows:

```
try {
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=nova.umuc.edu;dbname=cs495', $user, $pass); 
//check connection
}
catch (PDOException $e){
echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
```

A little bit of googling, and this seems to be because the driver isn't loaded in the configuration file (php.ini). I've looked at the php_info, and while the configuration file path is listed, it says no configuration file is loaded.  The PHP version is 5.2.13.

I've even gone to this directory on the server, and inside of that directory is a readme file that says this directory is depreciated for php's configuration file!  Is this something I can workaround, or does the server configuration have to change?

Comment: Are you running this as a web page? If so, run `phpinfo();` to see if `pdo_mysql` and `PDO` are there.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is seriously out of date, however. You should ask your school to upgrade, and whilst they are at it, ensure the MySQL database modules are loaded! The minimum they should be running is 5.4 these days, imo.

Comment: What halfer said, though its funny to me that your school is forcing you to use deprecated functions `mysql_` because that will be the only functions available. Do you have sudo access to the server?

Comment: Do you have to use school resources? Maybe install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on your own machine so you can use a version that's not so old.

Comment: No, I suppose I don't have to use school resources.  In fact, I'll just try to find a free hosting service somewhere.  I only need it for a week or two anyways.

Comment: Also, I would love to follow halfer's suggestion, however I already tried to get a hold of the tech support for the school.  One short, unfruitful chat session later, and I'm still waiting for a reply three days later.  I even stated that I think the configuration on the server is wrong.  I suppose they're not real concerned....